# Used Date function on left hand side of equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a portion of a SQL statement as shown below:

```
  WHERE  F.Organ=@OrganID 
  AND F.IsSubmitted = 0
  AND (DATEADD(day, ISNULL(F.DaysDue, 0), FV.DueDate)) < CONVERT(datetime,DATEADD("MINUTE",@UserOffset,GETUTCDATE()))
```

I have a DATEADD on the left hand side of the equal sign. The query works fine but is there an issue with having it as such?

Comment: Aside(?!): Lest anyone dyslexic see the obvious solution, it isn't anything special about the left hand vs. right hand. As a rule, any calculation involving data from the row(s) precludes the use of an index _seek_. (An index _scan_ may still provide some benefit.) And there are special cases, e.g. comparing `date` and `datetime` values where the query optimizer will do the right thing if you use something like `where DueDate <= Cast( GetDate() as Date );`. (I happen to be quasidextrous: equally bad with both hands.)

Comment: the usual convention, is to put the column on the left and the criteria on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's not S'argable, and won't use an index even if an appropriate index exists.

In many cases, you can transform to move the date function over to the right hand side.

As `@HABO` pointed out, there is nothing special about the left or right hand side of the filter criteria. Any calculation involving data from the row(s) precludes the use of an index seek (with some special exceptions such as `CAST(x AS date`)).

Comment: I suppose it won't help here to move the function, because it's on both hand sides.

Comment: @Sami - The right hand side is, effectively, a constant for any given execution of the statement, so it doesn't impact the performance. The left hand is checking against `DueDate` offset by `DaysDue` and will present a problem for performing an index seek. If so, you can create a _computed column_ and index it.

Comment: @HABO: I was greatly simplifying my answer in the first instance. Your comments are of course true